# How to run yocto developed raspberry pi image in qemu?

Tags: yocto, qemu, meta-raspberrypi

I'm compiling an image for raspberry-pi in yocto.How can i develop the same image to run in qemu.?

I included meta-raspberrypi in poky(sumo branch) along with its dependencies(meta-openembedded).I don't want to take the image,flash in SD-card and run in the hardware every time for simple tweaks.

MACHINE ??= "raspberrypi2"

This is what I have included in local.conf.
So how to run my image in qemu to check the changes are applied.What should I include in local.conf to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above was on the right track but chose the wrong machine.
In order to run the image built using the meta-raspberrypi package you need to
comment out the raspberrypi2 machine and set the machine to qemuarm.  The reason is
the processor on the raspi2 is a 32bit arm chip either a Broadcom 2836,or 2837 depending on the version of raspi2 you have. If you have a raspi1 B then likely a Broadcom 2835. You can look up the hardware here ([raspi-projects](https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/category/pi-hardware)) .

In your local.conf file change the lines to match those below .

```
    #MACHINE ??= "raspberrypi2"
    MACHINE ??= "qemuarm"
```

Build the image with

```
    $ bitbake core-image-base
    # or
    $ bitbake rpi-basic-imag # deprecated
```

Then you will have a qemu image that can be run with

```
    $ runqemu qemuarm
```

I have followed there steps myself and created the image I want, and am in the process of developing the system I need for a project. Hope this helps with others to move forward with similar goals.

Answer (score -1):

Try MACHINE = "qemux86-64", then bitbake your image, then use the runqemu script.

Comment: Raspberry has an arm cpu

Comment: Yes, but the image will not be run on raspberri pi, it will be run in qemu on a x86 host machine. The right setting for that environment is what I suggested. The image itself will contain exactly same userspace filesystem. The kernel and bootloader will be different to raspberri pi image, but it's almost certain that doesn't matter